# jProgressBar with Database

Tags: java, database, swing

how do I display the progress in a jProgressBar when I write something in the database?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have trouble displaying the `JProgressBar`?

Comment: No, I can display it, I just can't relate it with the database progress.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically use a [`SwingWorker`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to update the `JProgressBar` from the Event Dispatch thread whilst performing the database write operations on the background thread.  For example:

```
// Create progress bar to represent 10 items we wish to write to
// the database (hence min := 0, max := 10);
JProgressBar pBar = new JProgressBar(0, 10);

// TODO: Add progress bar to panel and display.

// Invoke SwingWorker to perform database write operations on
// background thread.
new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>() {
  /**
   * Called on background worker thread.  Performs DB write operations.
   */
  public Void doInBackground() {
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
      // TODO: Perform DB write operation here.

      // Publish progress so far back to Event Dispatch Thread.
      publish(i);
    }
  }

 /**
  * Called on EDT with intermediate progress result(s).
  */
 protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
   if (!chunks.isEmpty()) {
     int progress = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
     pBar.setValue(progress);
   }
 }      

 /**
  * Called on EDT when DB write task has completely finished.
  */
 protected void done() {
   pBar.setValue(pBar.getMaximum());
   // TODO: Hide progress bar, etc.
 }
}.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

On your server, you must collect the progress data and supply it in a way that jProgressBar can query it.